# Dynamically animate width of div when collapsed

Tags: angularjs, css

What I have so far:

#### [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/peser/1/edit)

Try to double click an item, and It'll show a child item. I want to animate it like that. I set the `width` to `300px`(static) just to show you how it works but, I want it to be `width:auto` (dynamic) but the animation is not working if I set it to `auto`.

How can I make it dynamic? for example the child div has more than 2 items inside it  or no items at all.

Comment: you can't make a css transition to 'auto' - you need a numeric value from your start to end point of the transition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack but you can use max-width instead of width and just set an upper bound for the resulting max-width.

http://jsbin.com/mibozupe/1/edit

```
.slides-child{
   display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:1;
  max-width: 500px;  
}
.slides-child.ng-hide{
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah it works from the example. I'll just check it first if it'll work on child > 2 || child < 2. Please wait.

Comment: It doesn't render correctly if the child is greater than 4.

Comment: I just increased the max-width from 500px to 2000px. I just hope that it won't exceed more than 10 childs. Haha Thanks rob!